# Logstash: Pipeline worker error, the pipeline will be stopped OrgJrubyExceptions SystemCallError

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

This is my workflow `filebeat -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana`

- logstash 7.8.1
- Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit

My logstash keeps getting shutdown unexpectedly after running successfully for sometime with below error
i'm not able to identify the reason for this error to look for solutions.

i had to restart `logstash` to load the data into `elasticsearch` whenever it gets shutdown.

Any suggestions are appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has been a while since i posted this question. i have figured out a solution for this problem, click this link to view the solution i posted in [github issues](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/11116#issuecomment-727234737).

**Reposting same answer below**

i moved from logstash barebone software installation to docker image.
As i expected, the docker container keeps running in the background without the issues that i have mentioned in my question. The container should be running in detached mode.

Below is the command that is used to run the logstash in docker container mode

```
docker run -d -p 9600:9600 -p 5044:5044 -v /home/elkuser/elkstack/softwares/logstash_file_docker/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml -v /home/elkuser/elkstack/softwares/logstash_file_docker/pipeline-final.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf cc67e625d974
```

Logstash docker image that is used `docker pull docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.8.1`

**References**

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
- https://www.docker.elastic.co/r/logstash/logstash:7.8.1